# convert Pdf to Executable

Tags: pdf

I am taking a intro to reversing course. After learning patching we got a home work to find the flag and write a writeup on how we did it. Part of the riddle is to figure out where exactly to find the flag. I was thinking maybe the pdf with the instructions on the home work has the flag in it. Is there a way to convert it to a executable format PE, so i can analyse it with IDA? If not what else can I do to find the flag if all I have is a pdf

Comment: what would the executable do?

Comment: Do the PDF instructions state where to download the binary from? Since it's a reversing course and not a file forensics course the flag should be in some executable binary that you download from somewhere.

Comment: I suggest you use a tool like `pdfStreamDumper.exe` to examine the PDF file for 'malicious` code.  The tool will list all the streams in the PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no conversion from pdf to PE and such conversion makes little sense.

A pdf can contain embedded javascript which can be defined as executable code in the broad sense.

There are some useful tools for analyzing pdf files here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220497/extract-javascript-from-malicious-pdf

A good starting point would be opening the file in a hex editor and looking for clues, maybe hidden instructions.